# Segment tree Lazy propagation & my code

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I am currently solving a problem on segment tree. I think the problem needs lazy propagation concept to be solved. As I'm very new to this concept, i'm having trouble with my code.

The problem in a nutshell is as follows:

initially, all array elements are 0 and they are indexed 0 to N-1

command 1. 0 x y v - updates value of each array indexes between x and y by v

command 2. 1 x y   - output the sum of all numbers between array index x & y.

Input starts with an integer T (≤ 5), denoting the number of test cases.

Each case contains two integers n (1 ≤ n ≤ 105) and q (1 ≤ q ≤ 50000). Each of the next q lines contains a task in one of the following form:

0 x y v (0 ≤ x ≤ y < n, 1 ≤ v ≤ 1000)

1 x y (0 ≤ x ≤ y < n)
For each case, print the case number first. Then for each query '1 x y', print the sum of all the array elements between x and y.
Here is my attempt:

```c
template<class T>
class SegmentTree
{
        T *tree,*update_tree;
        long size;

        public:
            SegmentTree(long N)
            {
                long x= (long)ceil(log2(N))+1;
                long size = 2*(long)pow(2,x);

                tree = new T[size];
                update_tree = new T[size];

                memset(tree,0,sizeof(tree));
                memset(update_tree,0,sizeof(update_tree));
            }

            void update(long node, long start, long end, long i, long j, long val)
            {
                if(start>j || end<i) return;
                if(start>=i && end<=j){
                    if(start==end){
                        tree[node]+=val;
                        return;
                    }
                    tree[node]+=val;
                    update_tree[2*node] += val;
                    update_tree[2*node+1]+=val;
                    return;
                }

                    long mid = (start+end)/2;
                update(2*node,start,mid,i,j,val);
                update(2*node+1,mid+1,end,i,j,val);
            }

            T query(long node, long start, long end, long i, long j, long val)
            {
                if(start>j || end<i) return -1;

                if(start>=i && end<=j)
                    return ((tree[node]+val)*(end-start+1));



                long a,b;
                a = update_tree[2*node];
                b = update_tree[2*node+1];

                 long mid = (start+end)/2;
                long val1 = query(2*node,start,mid,i,j,val+a);
                long val2 = query(2*node+1,mid+1,end,i,j,val+b);

                if(val1==-1)
                    return val2;
                if(val2==-1)
                    return val1;

                return val1+val2;

            }

};

int main()
{   
    long N,q,x,y,res;
    int tc=1, T,v,d;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(tc<=T)
    {
        scanf("%ld %ld",&N,&q);
        SegmentTree<long>s(N);

        printf("Case %d:\n",tc++);
        while(q--){
            scanf("%d",&d);
            if(!d){
                scanf("%ld %ld %d",&x,&y,&v);
                s.update(1,0,N-1,x,y,v);
            }
            else{
                scanf("%ld %ld",&x,&y);
                res = s.query(1,0,N-1,x,y,0);
                printf("%ld\n",res);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want lazy propagation (create elements only when they're going to be accessed/modified) or lazy evaluation (modify elements only when you try to read their value)? It seems your trying to achieve the latter.

Comment: I don't have any idea on lazy evaluation, just heard the term propagation and tried to code it.
I need to solve the problem, which has less complexity.

Comment: Perhaps it is overflowing?  The worst case query could require an answer of 105*50000*1000 which is more than will fit in a 32bit long.

Comment: it's not giving the correct answer. If you can't find any error, it's ok. then do you have any problem solved by lazy propagation correctly? give me that's code, i'll find the difference myself.
I think I'm quite unclear about the concept, and that's y not updating the tree in correct manner.